# Generate Signed Cloudfront URL using PHP

Tags: ios, url, amazon-cloudfront, signed

Does someone have a script or tutorial on how to generate a signed cloudfront url (with wildcard, so that it can be used more than once) using a php script?

I would like to use it for an iOS APP, but I read that is it not safe to generate the url on the app, and thus I would like to create a script on a server that will be called by the app to generate the signed url.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What about just using [the php code that AWS provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/cloudfront-signed-url.html)?

Comment: Ok, once this is done. I assume that I should secure the access to the php page? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: lol, well, that's a different question :): your app needs to exchange information with the php page that tells the page that the request is legitimate, and it needs to use https of course.